# Equivalent of set in ES6 to ES5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a set over which I am iterating in ES6. I am trying to convert it to its equivalent in ES5. My build is getting failed because of ES6. That's why I am converting it to ES5.

Here's my code in ES6

```
service.getDevices = function (date) {
        var result = [];
        var deviceList = devices[date.getTime()];

        for (let item of deviceList) { // browser compatibility: support for ECMA6
            result.push({"deviceName": item});
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I am getting error because of 'let'. I tried using `for (var item in deviceList)`, it does not display the charts.

I also tried this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < deviceList.length(); i++){
           result.push({"deviceName" : deviceList[i]});
       }
```

Even this is not working for set. can someone help and tell me how to iterate over a set in ES5 and if that is not possible, is there any equivalent way of doing it?

Comment: I think it's just that `length` is a property and not a function and therefor doesn't need the `()`

Comment: I don't see a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) here, just an array.

Comment: not only `let`, but `of` is not implemented.

Comment: is there any equivalent of let and of in ES5

Comment: Block level scoping of [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is not available in versions of JavaScript pre `ES6` however you can wrap your use of a var inside a function (with things like `forEach` or `map`) and use JavaScript's function level scoping. Knowing the datatype of `deviceList` is crucial in pointing you toward an optimal solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem with your second `for` example is just that `length` is a property and not a function so you shouldn't add `()` to the end of it.  A working version of this might look like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < deviceList.length; i++){
  result.push({"deviceName" : deviceList[i]});
}
```

This assumes (as [@grabantot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2277240/grabantot) pointed out) that `deviceList` is an array, however, if it's a `Set` then you need to use the `deviceList.size` property.

However, there is a more compatible version of your first `for` loop which is the `forEach()` function (which is available on [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach)), like this:

```
deviceList.forEach(function (item) {
  result.push({"deviceName": item});
});
```

Comment: The advantages of having a job where I literally do nothing :)

Comment: `Set` data type has `size` instead of `length`

Comment: Are you referring to this type? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: It has a length property, but it's always 0 and a size property which holds the length.  Nice of JavaScript keeping us on our toes! :)

Answer (score 7):

This is a basic set es5 class that I have used variations on over the years.

```js
function Set(items) {
  this._data = {};
  this.addItems(items);
}

Set.prototype.addItem = function(value) {
  this._data[value] = true;
  return this;
}

Set.prototype.removeItem = function(value) {
  delete this._data[value];
  return this;
}

Set.prototype.addItems = function(values) {
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    this.addItem(values[i]);
  }
  return this;
}

Set.prototype.removeItems = function(values) {
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    this.removeItem(values[i]);
  }
  return this;
}

Set.prototype.contains = function(value) {
  return !!this._data[value];
}

Set.prototype.reset = function() {
  this._data = {};
  return this;
}

Set.prototype.data = function() {
  return Object.keys(this._data);
}

Set.prototype.each = function(callback) {
  var data = this.data();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    callback(data[i]);
  }
}

var set = new Set(['a', 'b', 'c']);
console.log(set.addItems(['a', 'd', 'e']).removeItems(['b', 'e']).data());
console.log(set.contains('a'));
console.log(set.contains('e'));

set.each(console.log)
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not just iterate through the data and map the result with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
result = deviceList.map(function (item) {
    return { deviceName: item };
});
```

Comment: This approach is clean and very compatible: http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5

Comment: Interestingly, if the datatype of `deviceList` is a `Set` (which is only implied by the question and not specifically demonstrated in the code) then this approach will not work as there is no `Set.prototype.map()`

Comment: @JasonSperske, as i see it, op is talking about an array, because op is trying to get the `length` of it, wheras `Set` has a `size` and it is not accesable via bracket notation.