# Javascript : more clever way to filter thousands of row against thousands of values

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance

I've rows with 2 columns: product SKU and category ids
I need to only return the product SKU and their cat_ids that match a list of cat_ids
in SQL that would be :

```
SELECT SKU,cat_id FROM myTable where cat_id IN(my_huge cat_ids_list)
```

but I need to do this in Javascript from tab tab return data.

obviously, I could do it with two nested loops, but that would result in millions of comparisons and that would be too slow

if I have 30000 SKUs, to match against 1000 cat_ids that would at worst be 30M tests.

so is there a cleverer algorithmic approach that would filter this more globally, without needing so much tests ?

Many thanks

Comment: Maybe try a recursive approach?

Answer (score 1):

Use a hashset for your list of cat_ids, which gives you constant-time containment checks. Not too familiar with javascript, but I believe the `Set` type should do the trick.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 1):

You don't need nested loops. Use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which is constant time lookups. You need to create the set from the array of categories and then use `set.has()` to filter:

```js
let rows = [
    {sku: 1, cat_id:100},
    {sku: 11, cat_id:10},
    {sku: 12, cat_id:10},
    {sku: 13, cat_id:20},
    {sku: 14, cat_id:10},
    {sku: 15, cat_id:20},
    {sku: 16, cat_id:100}
]
//original array of ids to match
let matchCats = [10, 20]

// make a set from it
let matchSet = new Set(matchCats)

// filter with has()
let filtered = rows.filter(item => matchSet.has(item.cat_id))
console.log(filtered)
```

This should get you linear time filtering.

**Edit based on comment**
If you can't use ES6, you can still take advantage of the fact that regular javascript objects can be used like hashes with constant key lookup. It's not as pretty, but this should still work in linear time:

```js
let rows = [
    {sku: 1, cat_id:100},
    {sku: 11, cat_id:10},
    {sku: 12, cat_id:10},
    {sku: 13, cat_id:20},
    {sku: 14, cat_id:10},
    {sku: 15, cat_id:20},
    {sku: 16, cat_id:100}
]

let matchCats = [10, 20]

// make an object of key/null-value pairs
let matchObj = matchCats.reduce((obj, item) => (obj[item] = null, obj), {})
let filtered = rows.filter(item => item.cat_id in matchObj)
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Many thanks, looks cool but apparently, it doesn't seem to work with Duktape ECMA 5.1 javascript engine which I need to use

Comment: @glitchtracker you are correct Set is from ECMAScript 2015.  Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916610/equivalent-of-set-in-es6-to-es5) where someone wants a set command for ECMAScript 5.

Comment: @glitchtracker you can use a javascript object like a hash map. It's not as clean as a set because you are essentially using the keys like a set, but it's a decent option if you're stuck with es5. See edit for example.

Comment: Hi Mark, do you have sample code that would use "a javascript object like a hash map" I'm terribly newbie. Also, I tried Mac OS X JSC command line and doesn't run also, while JSC should support  ECMAScript 2015

Comment: Hi @glitchtracker, the edit I posted shows this. It creates an object with keys from this list of cat_ids and then uses  `in` to test if the object has the property to `filter()`